# ros-indigo-robot-upstart missing essential files

Tags: ros, package, robot-upstart, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I just installed the above mentioned package however it seems that its directory contains only a CMake file, templates and a few other useless files. The **install**  and **uninstall** scripts, although autocompleted when calling **rosrun robot_upstart ...**, are NOT present hence the package is completely useless.

Did I do something wrong or is this indeed a broken ROS package? If you clone the github repository you get all that you need.

Regards!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213987/ros-indigo-robot-upstart-missing-essential-files/) by [rbaleksandar](https://answers.ros.org/users/14216/rbaleksandar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 299 on 2015-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> The install and uninstall scripts, although autocompleted when calling `rosrun robot_upstart ...`, are NOT present hence the package is completely useless.

`rosrun` can only autocomplete things that are actually there. If I look at the [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/robot_upstart/blob/fd776b5d73fb702a017fb7c2db8505a60dfe41f7/CMakeLists.txt) for `robot_upstart` in its `indigo-devel` branch, the install targets [seem to be there](https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/robot_upstart/blob/fd776b5d73fb702a017fb7c2db8505a60dfe41f7/CMakeLists.txt#L9-L11):

```
file(GLOB SCRIPTS scripts/*)
install(PROGRAMS ${SCRIPTS} DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})
install(DIRECTORY templates DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION})
```

Could you perhaps be looking at the wrong directory? The package manifest and "CMake file, templates and a few other useless files" are installed in `/opt/ros/indigo/share/robot_upstart`, while the scripts should be in `/opt/ros/indigo/lib/robot_upstart`. The Python package `robot_upstart` should be in `/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/robot_upstart`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rbaleksandar](https://answers.ros.org/users/14216/rbaleksandar/) on 2015-07-17**:
Ah, yes, indeed I was looking in the wrong directory. Those things are in the lib folder of indigo's installation folder and also the Python package is there too. Thanks! PS: This still does not explain why rosrun was telling me that install and respectively uninstall could not be found.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-07-17**:
You did not mention or include any error from rosrun in your original post; please include the **exact** command you're running and it's **exact** output and we'll try to help.

**Comment by [rbaleksandar](https://answers.ros.org/users/14216/rbaleksandar/) on 2015-07-18**:
I forgot to use source on my .bashrc hence the changes in ROS' installation were not noticed and rosrun reported that "install" is not a known command. It's working now. :)